# Bootstrap下でtable td の幅を固定する方法が機能しない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

rails (4.2.6)bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.4)を使ってtableを表示しています。td幅を固定したいfieldがあり、`<th class="col-md-4">`, `<th class="col-md-4">` などを設定したのですが機能しません。なにが悪いかご指導下さい。

## トライアルした手順

1. テストプロジェクトを造りました

   ```
   rails new td_width_test
   ```
2. Gemfileは1行だけ追加

   ```
   gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.4'
   ```
3. controllerだけ作成

   ```
   rails g controller TdTest

   class TdTestController < ApplicationController
     def index
     end
   end
   ```
4. config/rootes.rbに2行追加

   ```
   root 'td_test#index'
   get '/td_test' => 'td_test#index'
   ```
5. view作成

   ```
   # app/views/td_test/index.html.erb
   <tr class="something">
      <td class="col-md-2">A</td>
      <td class="col-md-3">B</td>
      <td class="col-md-6">C</td> 
      <td class="col-md-1">D</td> 
   </tr> 
   </table>
   <teble class="trable">
     <tr class="something">
      <td >A</td>
      <td >B</td>
      <td >C</td> 
      <td >D</td> 
   </tr> 
   </table>
   ```
6. サーバ起動

   ```
    rails s&
   ```
7. firefox,Opera で確認

   ```
   localhost:3000
   ```

### 情報追加

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss を次の様にしています。

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets" ;
@import "bootstrap" ;
```

## 結果

いずれも以下のように詰まって表示されます
with class "col-md-2"
A B C D
without class
A B C D